# How to design high quality encoder-decoder pairs for images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing

In many of todays deep models for image processing you can find some sort of encoder-decoder structure, in the simplest form it is an Autoencoder, whenever we want to introduce some kind of bottleneck.

In my own experiments even in their simplest form (e.g. strided convolutions in the encoder, transposed convolutions in the decoder) they will produce quite blurry outputs or just with a general lack of detail. I noticed that adding a e.g. a discriminator can help with the sharpness but that can also introduce other artifacts. While I am aware that in practice you will lose some quality, I have also seen results that have a lot better quality output images, though rarely with public source code or sufficiently detailed descriptions of their architecture.

Similarly when you add (long) skip connections (like in u-net type networks) you do immediately get better results in terms of autoencoding, but then you basically circumvent the bottleneck that we need in many applications.

So how do you design an encoder-decoder pair with a bottle neck that still allows for high quality reconstructions? What losses should be used?

Comment: can you provide some references to these high quality autoencoders you talk about?

Comment: @shimao that is actually what I'm looking for! you can find examples in any papers that use some form of autoencoders, check out e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.04488.pdf)

Comment: can you provide some details on the architectures you've tried? so i can point out if anything immediately seems off.

Comment: @shimao sure, so the most simple form was chained `Conv(stride 2, doubling the channels), ReLU` blocks for the encoder, and the "reverse" `TranspConv(stride 2, halving the channels), ReLU` for the decoder (with and without instance normalization between the convolutions and activations), down to a lowest resolution of e.g. 4x4 2x2, or 1x1. Then I also tried replacing the transposed convs with e.g. bilinear/NN upsampling. or adding more (size preserving) convolutions to each resolution level. This is more or less what I had the impression was the "obvious" "simple" way to design these networks.

Comment: What I forgot to add is that at the very start of the encoder I ususally used a convolution with a larger kernel (like 5x5 or 7x7) to increase the number of channels to e.g. something between 32 and 128, and again one at the end of the decoder to reduce the number of channels again. thanks a lot for taking the time to look in to this!

Comment: A part of this problem has to do with the loss function used, https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/why-are-variational-autoencoders-output-is-blurred-while-gans-output-is-crisp-a